# Greatest Date group by TCP address

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group

**What I want:** I'm having problems with a greatest-n-per-group problem. My group is a set of TCP Addresses and the n is the date at which the table row was inserted into the database.

**The problem:** I'm currently getting all rows with tcp Addresses which match my where clause, rather then one with the largest date per tcp address.

I'm trying to follow this example and failing: [SQL Select only rows with Max Value on a Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column#7745635).

Here's what my table looks like.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `xactions` (
  `id` int(15) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `tcpAddress` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
   //a whole lot of other stuff in batween
  `date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=150 ;
```

Example rows are

```
ID | tcpAddress     | ...  | date
1  |  192.168.1.161 | ...  | 2012-09-12 14:19:39
2  |  192.168.1.162 | ...  | 2012-09-12 14:19:40
3  |  192.168.1.162 | ...  | 2012-09-12 14:19:41
4  |  192.168.1.162 | ...  | 2012-09-12 14:19:42
```

SQL statement I'm trying to use

```
select yt.id, yt.tcpAddress, yt.analog, yt.discrete, yt.counter, yt.date
from xactions yt
inner join(
    select id, tcpAddress, analog, discrete, counter, max(date) date
    from xactions
    WHERE tcpAddress='192.168.1.161' OR tcpAddress='192.168.1.162'
    group by date
) ss on yt.id = ss.id and yt.date= ss.date
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to group by the tcpAddress, not by the date.

And join by the tcpAddress, not the id.

```
select yt.id, yt.tcpAddress, yt.analog, yt.discrete, yt.counter, yt.date 
from xactions yt 
inner join ( 
  select tcpAddress, max(date) date 
  from xactions 
  where tcpAddress in ('192.168.1.161', '192.168.1.162')
  group by tcpAddress
 ) ss using (tcpAddress, date);
```

Also, you don't need to select any extra columns in the derived table -- only the tcpAddress and the max(date).

Comment: This worked for me. I was wondering Why I didn't have to select the extra columns from the derived table.

Answer (score 1):

Also you can use option with EXISTS(). In EXISTS() find MAX(date) for each group of tcpAddress
and compare them

```
SELECT id, tcpAddress, analog, discrete, counter, date
FROM xactions x1    
WHERE EXISTS (
              SELECT 1
              FROM xactions x2
              WHERE x1.tcpAddress = x2.tcpAddress
              HAVING MAX(x2.date) = x1.date
              ) AND (tcpAddress='192.168.1.161' OR tcpAddress='192.168.1.162')
```

Comment: First of all, thanks for taking the time to answer. phpmyadmin gave me this error. I'm using the latest version of WAMP. "...syntax to use near 'AND EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM xactions x2 ' at line 3"

Comment: So it doesn't have an error anymore but It seems to be returning all rows with tcpAddress = 192.168.1.161 and 192.168.1.162

Comment: sorry I forgot brackets for OR expression;) Try now please